# Google TV walk-through appears to be incorrect. Third party Add-ons?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, google-tv

I am attempting to build my first Google TV application and the documentation does not reflect the screens I am seeing.

The following URL is a walk-through to install the Google TV add-on ( https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_addon ).  I installed the recommended ADT (version 16.0.1), which doesn't have an "Android AVD and SDK Manager".  They appear to be separate modules within the ADT I installed.  Neither of them include "Third party Add-ons" as described in the walk-through.  As a result, I have installed quite a few SDKs and can't figure out how to make an AVD that supports Google TV.

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean 'it doesn't have an Android AVD and SDK Manager'?

Comment: The AVD Manager and SDK Manager are separate modules.  Under the window menu there are options for "Android SDK Manager" and "AVD Manager".  All screenshots in the walk-throughs I have found have a single option for "Android AVD and SDK Manager", which doesn't exist on this ADT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you on Linux? The Google TV AVD is limited to linux only at this point in time.

Also: Yes the "AVD and SDK Manager" got split up with the most recent tools. Use the "SDK Manager" to install new components and the "AVD Manager" to create emulator instances.

You can find the Google TV addon under API 12 (Android 3.1.) within the SDK manager, if you sort by API levels. Click the checkbox next to it and press "Install packages".

[image]

After you installed the addon, open the AVD manager and create a new AVD. Select "Google TV Addon (API 12)" under "Target".

Comment: I am not using Linux.  That must be my problem.  At least I'm not going crazy.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't have the GoogleTV option at all on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The walkthrough directs you to install the SDK, which has these tools. The tool is the program "android".

Comment: Which SDK?  I have installed Android 4.0.3 (API 15), 2.1 (API 7), and all of the Extras listed in the SDK Manager.

Comment: The latest SDK is version 16, but, all versions of the SDK contain these tools. I'm just telling you that you do have these tools, they're in the SDK, and not part of ADT.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  Please confirm that your previous statement is correct.  I am running this on a windows platform so I don't believe I have these tools available to me.  Based on the response from alextsc, The Google TV AVD is only available on Linux.

Comment: Both are correct. You do have the AVD and SDK manager. You may not have access to all of the plug-ins and addons that are managed by these tools.